# Are JVM heap/stack different than virtual address space heap/stack?

Tags: jvm, stack, heap-memory, segment, object-files

Memory is divided into "segments" called heap, stack, bss, data, and text. However, the JVM also has these concepts of stack and heap. So how are these two reconciled?

Are they different levels of abstraction, where main memory is one or two levels below the JVM, and whose "segments" maps naturally to JVM's "segments"? Since JVM is supposed to be a virtual computer, it seems to me like they emulate what happens underneath but at a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: The main memory may be a level or two below the JVM’s memory management, but surly, the terms you’ve mentioned do no exist at those levels. bss, data, and text are terms I only know from *file formats*, as the difference between bss and data lies in the way they are stored in an executable file or link library, not in the way they are used at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you've been reading a textbook or similar. All these terms generally have very precise definitions in books/lectures, but a lot less precise definitions in reality. Therefore what people mean when they say heap is not necessarily exactly the same as what a book etc. says.

> Memory is divided into "segments" called heap, stack, bss, data, and text.

This is only true for a typical user space process. In other word this will be true for an everyday program written in c or similar, however it is not true for all programs, and definitely not true for the entire memory space.

When a program is executed the OS allocates memory for the various segments listed, except the the heap. The program can request memory from the OS while it is executing. This allows a program to use a different amount of memory depending on its needs. The heap refers to memory requested by the program usually via a function like malloc. To clarify the heap typically refers to a managed region of memory, usually managed with malloc/free. It is also possible to request memory directly from the OS, in an unmanaged fashion. Most people (Imo) would say this wouldn't count as part of the heap.

The stack is a data structure/segment which keeps track of local variables and function calls. It stores important information like where to return after a function call. In c or other "native" languages the stack is created by the OS and can grow or shrink if needed.

Java allows program to request memory during execution using new. Memory allocated to a java program using new is referred to as memory in the java heap. One could imagine that if you where implementing a Jvm you would use malloc behind the scenes of new. This would result in a java heap within a regular native heap. In reality "serious" jvms do not do this and interact directly with the OS for memory.

In Java the stack is created by the Jvm. One could imagine that this is allocated by malloc, but as with the heap this is likely not how real world jvms do it.

Edit:
A Jvm like hotspot. Would likely allocate memory directly from the OS. This memory would then get put into some kind of pool, from which it would be removed as needed. Reasons for needed memory would be needed includes new, or a stack that needs to grow.